# Transform Regexp to POSIX BRE

Tags: regex, logging, scom

I'd like to put this expression into POSIX BRE.

```
HTTP\/[\d.]+.\s+(?:403)\s+(4[0-9])\s+
```

Here is what I've come up with so far.

```
HTTP\/[0-9.]{1,}.[[:blank:]]{1,}403[[:blank:]]{1,}(4[0-9])[[:blank:]]
```

Using a web based regex checker, both examples work quite well.
This regexp needs to be registered in SCOM however and it seems like it only supports POSIX BRE for monitoring Linux servers.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Posix documentation on [Basic Regular Expressions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03). In particular, note:

> 5. When a BRE matching a single character, a subexpression, or a back-reference is followed by an interval expression of the format `\{m\}`, `\{m,\}`, or `\{m,n\}`, together with that interval expression it shall match what repeated consecutive occurrences of the BRE would match…

So `[[:blank:]]{1,}` isn't going to do what you think it will; the braces need to be preceded with backslashes.

On the other hand, most BRE implementations do allow you to use `\+` to mean "one or more repetitions". At least, the BSD and Gnu varieties do. So you might well be able to write that as `[[:blank:]]\+` instead of using the numeric repetition operator `[[:blank:]]\{1,\}`.

Finally, `[[:blank:]]` might not be what you want. At least, it doesn't match the same thing as `\s` does. `[[:blank:]]` matches only space and tab characters (`[ \t]`). But in most regex libraries, `\s` is the same as `[ \t\r\n\f\v]`, which is what is matched by `[[:space:]]` in a C regex (or by the `isspace()` function in C code).  The most visible difference between `[[:blank:]]` and `\s` (or `[[:space:]]`) is that `[[:blank:]]` does not match newlines. Perhaps that's fine in your application.

**Pedantic note:** Some regex libraries define `\s` as `[ \t\r\n\f]`, but you're unlikely to notice the difference. And all of those lists of characters assume that the regex has been compiled in the "C" locale. If the regex library is locale-aware and some other locale has been enabled, additional characters might match.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I should have mentioned that the SCOM Linux agent is monitoring a nginx logfile for the part HTTP/1.1" 403 48 (where the number after the error code 403 is a two digit number in the range 40-49)
sometext HTTP/1.1" 403 48 "-" "sometext"

Comment: Also `(` and `)` need to be backslashed, and on the other hand there is no need to backslash `/` (unless your tool uses literal slashes as the regex delmiter in the host language's syntax, for example).